# java-- dictionary using AVL trees

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, avl-tree

I'm currently creating a dictionary using java and implementing an [AVL tree][1]. 
for the text file I am trying to read as an input, and the words are written on different lines than their meanings. For example one of them is:

ACADIAN
A*ca"di*an, a.

Defn: Of or pertaining to Acadie, or Nova Scotia. "Acadian farmers."
Longfellow.
 -- n.

Defn: A native of Acadie. Acadian epoch (Geol.), an epoch at the
beginning of the American paleozoic time, and including the oldest
American rocks known to be fossiliferous. See Geology.
 -- Acadian owl (Zoöl.), a small North American owl (Nyctule
Acadica); the saw-whet.

---

As you can see, the word is one line while the actual meaning can be various lines. I want to store the actual word into String word; and the meaning into String meaning; 
unfortunately, I originally wrote the program to have the word and meaning all on one line, making it much easier and now I am having trouble trying to fix it.

Here is my original code:

```
 while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        String read = sc.nextLine();
        String arr[] = read.split(" ");
        String word = arr[0];
        String meaning = read.substring(arr[0].length()+1);
        tree.Root = tree.insert(tree.Root,word,meaning);
   }
```

im trying to modify it so I can assign word to one line and then meaning to the definition.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question

Comment: I could be a bit complex than your loop, save the line as prevLine, read the next line, if the next line is empty-line then probably prevLine is your word line, keep it as wordLine, then read the next line, if it starts with Defn: then this is your word's definition, then read all the lines until you reach an empty line. It could be other definitions, so take care them like previous definition as well, After an empty line if the next line does not start with Defn probably you reached the other Word. repeat yourself again

Comment: Thank you so much!! I see what you're saying, this could definitely work. I will try it out.